# apache server serving index.html instead of index.php, after changing the file preference inside the dir.conf file

Tags: php, apache2

I changed the file preference inside the dir.conf file:

```
$sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

This means that index.php will get first preference, right?

In `/var/www/html` i have two files i.e index.html and index.php.
But when i visit my ip_address in my browser, the index.html is being served instead of index.php. Am i missing out something?

Comment: actually it is not serving any of those two files. It is showing "currently unable to handle this request."

Comment: if the error is "currently unable to handle this request", it may be due to code issues in the php file . Please amend the index.php to a simple one such as <?php echo "test"; ?> and see the result

Comment: its working now. dont know what i did wrong. actualy i was trying <?php phpinfo(); ?>.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `dir.conf` file :

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Comment: aren't we suppose to place the index.php in the left most so that it will get the first preference.